# SQLCODE 42601 when declaring a continue handler for an IBM DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2, syntax-error

I tried to find a solution here but couldn't find any. This is some script I'm trying to run :

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' BEGIN END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE (JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,'
    || 'VERSION BIGINT ,'
    || 'JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,'
    || 'JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,'
    || 'constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY));';
END
```

It creates a table and if the table already exists the exception that's thrown is ignored. This is the error I get when I try to run the script :

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END;LSTATE '42710' BEGIN;<psm_semicolon>

I've tried to fix a lot of things in that code, tried to add some meaningless code between the `BEGIN` and `END` statements (which is otherwise just an empty procedure). Nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the empty `BEGIN END`

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710'
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE (JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,'
    || 'VERSION BIGINT ,'
    || 'JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,'
    || 'JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,'
    || 'constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY));';
END
```

Comment: Kept giving an error. I removed the semicolon, that worked. For some reason if I use the code as a schema for Spring Batch it keeps giving errors, but running it in a console is fine.

Comment: The first, I suppose it expects a block.

Comment: I removed the extra semicolon

Comment: I saw it, I also had to copy-paste the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ...` block (duplicate it). I don't know DB2 syntax very well so I'm guessing what it wanted was a proper block of code to execute when the 42710 error occurs (so an empty execution block like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''` should be fine). And then I run my actual code. This was for Spring Batch configuration, I encountered it when trying to run a custom schema. It got distracted and used the wrong annotation (the JPA one instead of the Spring Batch one), and using the right one fixed the problem (exceptions are ignored so no handler required).